# Filter pandas dataframe if string exists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with species name in one column, and additional information (RNA type) in another. For a given species name, if there is no RNA type information in the other rows of the dataframe, I want to retain this row (for example 5th row below for Species2), but if there is RNA type information in other rows, remove the rows which have NaN (for example 4th row below for Species1).

| Sample | Species_name | RNA_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Species1 | RNA1 |
| A1 | Species1 | RNA2 |
| A1 | Species1 | RNA3 |
| A1 | Species1 | NaN (remove) |
| A1 | Species2 | NaN (retain) |

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Try to this:

```
df = df[~((df["Species_name"].duplicated(keep=False))&(df["RNA_type"].isnull()))]
```

Comment: That's a much more elegant solution.